# JPA Specification using a minversion of the Entitry

Tags: jpa, specifications

How do i create a mini version of an enitity in to use inside a jpa specificaiton. Is that possible.

```
Specification<Student> studentFinalSpecification = studentSpecification1
                        .and(studentSpecificaiton2);
StudentRepository.findAll(studentfinalSpecification );
```

Instead of this i would like to create a miniature version of Student like StudentMini using few feids
essential from student.

```
Specification<StudentMini> studentMinifinalSpecification = studentSpecification1
                        .and(studentSpecificaiton2);
StudentFinalRepository.findAll(studentfinalSpecification );
```

and if student has relation to school then i would like to use schoolMini relation inside studentMini.

Is it possible to create this way without creating tables for studentMini and schoolMini

Answer (score 0):

"Yes, you can map two or more entities to the same database table. But you should only do that if you will use all of these entities to perform write operations or to define associations between entities. If that’s not the case, you should better use a DTO projection."

read ->

> https://thorben-janssen.com/hibernate-tips-map-multiple-entities-same-table/